# How bad is a leak-through?

Tags: drywall, water

I replaced a Fluidmaster in a toilet, and I suspect the fill valve was slightly loose because, after about 12 hours there was a small puddle in the bathroom and the ceiling below was damp. I turned off the water and dried everything, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Can I just spackle and repaint the affected portion of ceiling, or does the drywall need to be removed? Will a one-time incident like this likely cause significant water damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the damage is fairly small and the paper on the sheetrock has not bubbled or separated, just let it dry out well and prime the water stained area with Bins pigmented shellac, then paint the area. Hopefully you will get a good color match as a touch up.

Comment: Will using a sealing primer like KILZ do the same thing?

Comment: If the stains are not too bad, a couple coats of Kilz should work. Don't be surprised if you see some bleed through of the stain after one coat. Any latex product is susceptible to bleed through. A shellac primer is really the best solution.